# Polymer - Creating an equally spaced, dynamic horizontal layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I am using the `core-scaffold` component to make a list of objects a shown below. My goal is to put 2 items on each row which share the space 50% -50% . However Horizontal layout fails to allocate space with this ratio. How can I achieve equal spacing.

Secondly, when the screen size gets small, I want the horizontal layout to change into a vertical layout so that, as again shown in the picture, items are not compressed. What is a good way to achieve dynamic layout ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the core-media-query element to capture responsive changes:

```
<core-media-query query="max-width: 600px" queryMatches="{{phoneScreen}}">
</core-media-query>
```

Use the flex attribute on your columns to get the 50-50 width. Also use the {{phoneScreen}} (set by the core-media-query) to determine if we should use the horizontal layout or not

```
<div class="row" horizontal?="{{!phoneScreen}}" layout>
   <div class="panel" flex>50%</div>
   <div class="panel" flex>50%</div>
</div>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WxUFCWFQVMeBgXSLI32M?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Polymer offers now the app-layout > app-grid helper class.

1.Import the app-grid-style.html which can be found in the app-layout in the bower_components folder.
2.Include include="app-grid-style" in the style section of your custom element.
3.And add the class app-grid to the container which will hold the layout.
A basic example can be found on this Polymer link.
[Polymer app-grid documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-grid)